# How we calculate Precision-Recall Curve?

Tags: image-segmentation, classification, machine-learning

As far as I know, precision and recall are two single values. How we can plot a curve from these two single values? I think I should calculate a set of values for each of them but how?

afterwards, the curve can be depicted by using the fact that they are inversely related.

$$
\text{Precision}=\frac{tp}{tp+fp} 
$$
$$
\text{Recall}=\frac{tp}{tp+fn}
$$
Where $tp = \text{True Positives}$, $fp = \text{False Positives}$ and $fn = \text{False Negatives}$.

Anybody can explain how we can plot a curve from two single values?

One answer can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-compute-precision-recall-curves) but I do not believe that I have caught the point well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. When you just have a single precision and a single recall value, you get a precision-recall point, not a curve.

However, machine learning models typically do not output discrete categories, even when such models fall into the "classification" paradigm (which is why, for instance, [Frank Harrell dislikes the term "classification"](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/)).

For instance, a logistic regression or a neural network, using a method like `model.predict_proba` in Python (not just `model.predict`), will return values on a continuum. The `model.predict` method will predict the category with the highest predicted value in `predict_proba`, but that is a stage on top of the logistic regression or neural network itself, a stage that combines the machine learning model output with a decision rule about what to do with that output.

You get the precision-recall curve by choosing multiple decision rules, calculating the precision and recall for each decision rule, and plotting those precision-recall pairs. The multiple decision rules have to do with thresholds. As logistic regression (especially) and neural network outputs are often on the interval $[0,1]$, they can be interpreted as probabilities. The default decision rule (such as in `model.predict`) is to assign to category $0$ if the probability of category $1$ (which is what is predicted) is less than $0.5$, otherwise category $1$. Another decision rule might use a threshold of $0.2$ or $0.9$ instead of $0.5$.

Loop over many thresholds to produce an entire PR curve. In the code below, I let `sklearn` calculate the thresholds, but if you set the `thresholds` in `for value in thresholds` to be something like `np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)`, you will get similar results.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, precision_score, recall_score
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2024)

# Define some simulated model predictions and binary outcomes
#
preds = np.random.beta(1/3, 1/3, 1000)
truth = np.random.binomial(1, preds, len(preds))

# Calculate the PR curve in sklearn
#
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(truth, preds)

# Loop over various thresholds to calculate the PR curve ourselves
#
precision_self = []
recall_self = []
for value in thresholds:
    
    # Assign categorical predictions according to the side of the threshold on which
    # the prediction falls
    # Category 0 if < threshold
    # Category 1 otherwise
    #
    categories = [0 if item < value else 1 for item in preds]
    
    # Calculate the precision and recall scores
    #
    precision_self.append(precision_score(truth, categories))
    recall_self.append(recall_score(truth, categories))
    
# Plot it out to see that we get the same curve either way
#
plt.plot(recall, precision, label = "sklearn", linewidth = 7)
plt.plot(recall_self, precision_self, label = "self", linewidth = 3)
plt.xlabel("Recall")
plt.ylabel("Precision")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: sklearn vs self-implementation]

A critical piece to keep in mind is that many of these machine learning models called "classifiers" do not do classification on their own. They predict on a continuum, and then some decision rule can, [but does not have to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274) and [arguably should not](https://hbiostat.org/blog/post/class-damage/index.html), convert those predictions on a continuum to categories, and there are many possible decision rules, each of which has its own recall and precision values.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you can't plot a curve from a single pair of values, so you have to find a parameter to vary that changes your problem in a way that makes sense to what you're trying to do.

For example, suppose your binary classification problem has a choosable threshold.  If you vary the threshold up and down, then it will change the precision and recall.

Then you might get a plot like the one below.  R code below that generated it.

[image]

---

**R Code**

```
#26568

Ndata <- 1000

c1 <- runif(Ndata,1.5,3)
c2 <- runif(Ndata,1,2.5)

data <- c(c1, c2)

thresholds <- seq(1,2.99,0.01)

precision <- thresholds*0
recall <- thresholds*0

for (k in 1:length(thresholds))
{
  threshold <- thresholds[k]
  cl <- data*0
  tp <- 0
  tn <- 0
  fp <- 0
  fn <- 0

  for (i in 1:length(data))
  {
    if ( (data[i] > threshold) && (i <= Ndata))
    {
      tp <- tp + 1  
    }
    if ( (data[i] > threshold) && (i > Ndata))
    {
      fp <- fp + 1  
    }
    if ( (data[i] <= threshold) && (i <= Ndata))
    {
      fn <- fn + 1  
    }
    if ( (data[i] <= threshold) && (i > Ndata))
    {
      tn <- tn + 1  
    }
  }

  precision[k] <- tp / (tp + fp)
  recall[k] <- tp / (tp  + fn)
}

plot(precision,recall)
```